# Dynamically Populate Sum by Dates

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula, pivot-table, excel-2013

I'm hoping someone can help me build a quick function in Excel or an auto-populated table which sums an amount based upon what sales were done on a daily basis.

#### Example Table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
date    |   gross amt.
------------------------------
1/1/14  |  $200
1/1/14  |  $100
1/1/14  |  $300
1/4/14  |  $999
1/7/14  |  $500
1/13/14 |  $100
```

#### Table that will need to be created

```
--------------------------------------------------
date    |   total amount  |  # entries
------------------------------
1/1/14  |  $600   |   3
1/4/14  |  $999   |   1
1/7/14  |  $500   |   1
1/13/14 |  $100   |   1
```

For such a simple table I obviously can use a SUM function and just type the dates on which sales occur.  Unfortunately, I have numerous tables where some may have 50 entries on one date yet 2 on another date, or 2 on one date and 50 on another.

I was thinking of some sort of dynamic range but would like to know, what would be a sensible approach?

Comment: @pnuts I have looked into it to configure but I dont think it will work for my application, unless you advise otherwise for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would appear may be of use:

[image: SO26221265 example]

Comment: Okay, that should work!  But now how can I insert the `count` of how many sales during the day into the same pivottable

Comment: I need to know how many of each date entry occur (essentially how many sales occurred on any one given date)

Comment: ahhh! I got it, it was under field settings...  it was 1/1 = 3; 1/4 = 1;  1/7 = 1;  etc.etc.

Comment: Dang!  Now I have one problem!  I cant add another column as needed to the same pivottable!  I can only select either the count of them or either the sum of them.  How can I have two formulas run from the same information?